# How to include hidapi in visual studio 2015 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, hidapi

I'm trying to use the hidapi library on Visual Studio 2015 for a c++ console app.

I've included hidapi.h as a header file, but can't seem to figure out how to link the dll. I've scoured this site looking for solutions to including other libraries but they seem specific for each case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to build it (instructions: http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) and link with the import library for the generated dll.

Comment: @Richard Critten I've built the .sln file as per those instructions, but how exactly do I "link with the import library for the generated dll"?

Answer (score 1):

1.If you already have the hidapi.lib and hidapi.dll files, go to project->properties->configuration properties->linker->additional dependencies and add you .lib file's path

2. if your project is working under x64 ,add your hidapi.dll file in the  C:\Windows\System32. Otherwise, add it in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64